# How to generate expiration time for refresh token?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I need to generate the expiration time for refresh token, refresh token should expires in 200 days, how to generate exp time for this? Is there any libraries? And what format should be? unix, maybe YYYY/MM/DD etc? Any options please, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use json web tokens and make use of the `jsonwebtoken` package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Specifically, if you make use of the `options.expiresIn` value this will take care of the date calculations and logic for you. When using the `verify()` method it will fail if the token has expired.

Comment: Is it okay if the refresh token is generated as an access token using the jsonwebtoken package? Because now i generate refresh token using rand-token package, so refresh token is just a random string, for example: GFZCdUw4ds0kRxeYaFU6jSETCRhqC3kQXBlmrLC3YB2uySg8irzH3LkB8BXSXQioT and i need to specify the expiration time for this string.

Comment: Personally I like the notion of using json web tokens for access and refresh tokens. You can therefor within the token itself, hold when it expires making it extremely easy for clients to check whether they need to use the refresh token or not. The only difference is that it may be slightly larger in size. If you wanted to use the random token package, you could use something like Moment.js to generate the expiration time for you. `moment().add(200, 'days').toISOString()` which will generate the date in ISO 8601 format `2013-02-13T22:44:30.652Z`